# Condicional if que compara constructor con clase

Tags: javascript, poo

Estudiando introducción a la POO me encontré con el siguiente código, en el cual un instructor pone el siguiente IF para evitar que a la clase padre no se le puedan modificar instancias:

```js
export class Cuenta{
    
    #cliente;
    #saldo;

    constructor(cliente, numero, agencia, saldo) {
        if(this.constructor == Cuenta){
            throw new Error ('No dispone acceso para instanciar objetos de esta clase');
        }
        this.#cliente = cliente;
        this.numero = numero;
        this.agencia = agencia;
        this.#saldo = saldo;
    }
```

Mi duda es qué es lo que compara el condicional siendo que `constructor` es un método y *Cuenta* una clase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo más fácil es poner un console.log

```js
class A{
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor);
        console.log("==============");
        console.log(A);
    }
}
new A();
```

Con esto puedes ver que tanto this.constructor y la clase A (la clase en cuestión) retornan la implementación de la clase.

Entonces si ambos valores son iguales, arroja un error evitando de esta manera poder instanciar la clase.

La pregunta interesante es: ***¿Por qué hacer esto?***

Hoy Javascript debe ser el lenguaje más ampliamente usado por lejos, pero eso no quita que es un pésimo lenguaje, y cuando aprendes la historia de cómo nace entiendes la razón. A traves de los años se han hecho mejoras, pero es solo más pegamento a un jarrón roto. Una de estas mejoras fue la integración del paradigma POO. Pero como no podía ser de otra manera, no fue bien implementado (porque la verdad era imposible hacerlo). Entonces faltan conceptos comunes de POO como por ejemplo elementos privados o en este caso clases [Abstractas](https://informaticapc.com/poo/clases-abstractas.php).

Una clase abstracta en términos teóricos permite concebir una supra entidad que no es una entidad del negocio. Y en términos prácticos, es una clase que no puede ser instanciada pero de la que derivan otras clases.

Podría ser la clase "Documento" y tener clases derivas como "Boleta" y "Factura". Una entidad documento no existe en el negocio más allá de ser un concepto abstracto (ahí el nombre) pero si existen Boletas y Facturas.

Entonces, en Javascript no queda más que usar este tipo de truco, el cual consiste en impedir la instanciación de una Clase comparando this.constructor con la Clase misma. Y aprovechar que el scope de `this` cambia al ser una Clase derivada. Por ejemplo:

```js
class A{
    constructor() {
        console.log(this.constructor);
        console.log("==============");
        console.log(A);
    }
}
class B extends A{
  constructor(){
     super();
  }
}
new B();
```

Como veras this.constructor aun cuando está en la "Clase A" retorna la "Clase B" porque su scope es está en esta última. Y gracias a esto podemos crear Clases Abstractas en un lenguaje que no lo tiene implementado.

Comment: Excelente, gracias !!!